# Execute script into Jenkins file system from the job

Tags: jenkins, filesystems, execute, workspace

I am a Jenkins newbie, so I am sorry if this question looks so. I would like to execute batch command from Jenkins master, which can execute script stored into Jenkins file system, so NOT into workspace created by Jenkins into my local D:/... .
I am trying from Execute Windows batch command field:
start https://our.jenkins.in.company.cz/var/jenkins_home/HELLO/hello.py
but Jenkins cannot find the file:
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    /var/jenkins_home/HELLO/hello.py
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Stapler

R/W/X rights for the script are allowed.

Please let me know how to achieve the right way.
Thank you very very much.

Comment: The file is located in Jenkins file system here:
/home/some-user/mount/HELLO/hello.py

Comment: What is the way of execution? pipeline? freestyle job?

Comment: It is freestyle job

Comment: can you update the question with the command? Or this is?
"start https://our.jenkins.in.company.cz/var/jenkins_home/HELLO/hello.py"

Answer (score 0):

I assume the python was installed on the machine.

May you can run the script with the following command:

```
python /home/some-user/mount/HELLO/hello.py
```

But I am little bit confused, because you wrote about an Windows batch command and "D:/" path which assume you work on windows system but /home/some-user/mount/HELLO/hello.py assume something is linux based system.

The `start` as I see works with `.exe` runnable, you need to tell exactly to run a script with python, this is the first part of the command.

If you using windows with linux subsystem, may you can run something like this as I remember correctly:

```
python D:\windowspath_to_subsytem\home\some-user\mount\HELLO\hello.py
```